# Frustrating problem with NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, nstextview

I want to print out the Text contents of a `NSTextView` using the `NSLog` function in Objective-C. The code I have so far is:

`NSString *s=[updateSource textStorage];`

`NSLog(s);`

All I get is the error:

`[NSConcreteTextStorage getCharacters:range:]: selector not recognized [self = 0x43f4b0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the cause of your problem, but you should be using NSLog(@"%@",s); to log your string. The first argument of NSLog should always be a format string, and not the value you're trying to log.

(if you don't, your app will likely crash if the value contains percent characters)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[updateSource string]` instead. `[updateSource textStorage]` is not an `NSString`, but rather an `NSTextStorage`.

Comment: If you have NSTextStorage and need to print what it stores, you need to ask it for it's `-string`.  Otherwise if you have access to the actual NSTextView, just call `-string` there.